# CSS change color of web icon, html customize wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, colors

I am trying to customize a plugin, basically trying to change the color of a icon. 
I am able to set the default color of the icon to black with this -

```
    [class^="myplugin-"]:before, [class*=" myplugin-"]:before {
    color: black;
    }
```

My problem is on hover I'm not able to change the icon color to white or any. Inspecting element i found this-

```
   <div class = "myplugin-container">
   <ul>
   <li class = "myplugin-btn-google">
   <a title=....>
   <span class="myplugin-icon">
   <i class = "myplugin myplugin-google"</i>
   </span>
   </a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

I tried the following. It is changing only the span color to white but not the actual icon color -

```
  .myplugin-container li.myplugin-btn-google a:hover span{
   color: red;
   background: white;
   }
```

My assumption is I'm not selecting the right sub-class. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you problem is being caused by:

```
.myplugin-container li.myplugin-btn-google a:hover span{
```

Which means that only the link which have no background is being changed and the actual element you want to change.

If you want to change `myplugin-container` background color, then the easiest way would be:

```
.myplugin-container{ background: white; }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above code you mention is changing the whole div section background area. My goal is to change the color of i section class on hover, not the background color. My code above on span is working fine for background color but not able to change the true fontcolor like my first code above is changing to whatever color I want on default.

Comment: you can change the element class name to your icon class name.

Comment: Or try `.myplugin-container li.myplugin-btn-google a span:hover{}` and see if works.

Comment: Same result. Only span background color is changing on mouse hover. I'm guessing the font is below this level because while changing the background color it seems like the actual font is underneath the span, may be the i tag.